# Values inside filters in caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to understand the following part in caffe network model.

```
 convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
}
```

What I understood is there are 256 filters used in this layer.
I want to know how the values inside those filters are selected ?
Using size 5x5 and by std dev 0.01 we can create one filter, how other filters are created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the input dimension to this layer (the "channel" shape) this layer has 256 filters of shape `in-dim`-by-`5`-by-`5`. Caffe init all these values (according to `weight_filler` param) with i.i.d random samples from a Gaussian (normal) distribution with zero mean and std=0.01.

You can see the values in python (assuming the layer name is `"conv1"`):

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/net.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
layer_idx = list(net._layer_names).index('conv1')
weights = net.layers[layer_idx].blobs[0].data
print "filter values =", weights
```